# How to find out why a MFC program closes silently

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, mfc

I have the following bug in a program:

An MDI MFC program closes silently on Windows 7 (terminates the process without prompting to save changes and without displaying any "crash" dialog) when the user performs this operation : Click a context menu item.
But this happens only on that PC, at least, for the moment. No other PC has encountered that problem. However the bug can always be reproduced following the same steps but only on that PC.

I want to know the reason but probably the customer won't allow me to install many programs to debug, so I need to be able to log when the program terminates, or print the stack in Release version but I'm quite lost.
I had faced a similar bug before and eventually I fixed it logging line by line and changing the problematic part, but I guess there are much better ways to find bug reasons than this.

I have tried on my development PC to create minidumps on Release mode but if there is no exception thrown on that PC, (I haven't confirmed that yet, though...) maybe it's pointless.
Also used an available class on codeproject (Stackwalker) but I don't manage to print all the function calls. Only on simple console programs, but not on MDI or even SDI.

Any ideas on how to find out the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked with the user to see if a dump file is created locally on the pc.  If not, there are ways to trap one.

Comment: What is your code doing when that context menu item is clicked?

Comment: Is the context menu created by your code?

Comment: OK, I fixed the problem but I'm more confused now.
The PC had 32 bit machine and I couldn't find any event, just close.
After talking with the user, allowed me to install Visual Studio 2010 on it.

Then a "Runtime Error: R605 - pure virtual function call appeared." dialog box appeared when running on Release Mode and on debug mode nothing happened.

But I was sure that I didn't call a virtual function call.

Comment: Is it possible that the Visual C++ Runtime Library got corrupted???
I think this, because the original version of the program got fixed when I installed VS 2010 on the user computer...